# Https without www not working in aws route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, amazon-route53, no-www

i have domain for example, example.com so,

```
http://www.example.com ( works ),
https://www.example.com ( works ),
http://example.com ( works ),
https://example.com ( does not work)
```

so how can i make https://example.com work ? i have two ports listening on my aws elastic beanstalk i.e. 80 and 443, and only 443 has ssl on it, and any request coming to port 80 is forwarded to 443, any help regarding it is appreciated... thanks in advance

Comment: There are many possible causes. Edit your question and include the output from this command `curl -v https://example.com`. Of course, use your real site URL.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html

> Note
>
> When you request a wildcard certificate, the asterisk (*) must be
> in the leftmost position of the domain name and can protect only one
> subdomain level. For example, *.example.com can protect
> login.example.com and test.example.com, but it cannot protect
> test.login.example.com. **Also note that *.example.com protects only the**
> **subdomains of example.com, it does not protect the bare or apex domain**
> **(example.com).** However, you can request a certificate that protects a
> bare or apex domain and its subdomains by specifying multiple domain
> names in your request. For example, you can request a certificate that
> protects example.com and *.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using ACM certificates?
If so: do you have multiple domain names ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com) defined for the certificate?
You can also set Wildcards like *.example.com

See more here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/acm-certificate.html

Comment: yes its ACM &i have setup two www.example.com & example.com

Comment: will setting up *.example.com will solve this ? i doubt it because in the documentation no where its mentioned anything related to this